# Accessing a Tab inside an Accordian - JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to get the index of the selected tab of a "tabs" object inside of an Accordian in JQuery UI and store it in a variable.  The problem is, I don't know how to select the tab that is inside the active accordian window. So far I have this:

```
var active_acc = $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" );  //Returns accordian index that is open
var active_tab = $( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected" );  //Gets a tab index, but not the one in the open accordian.
```

I have been trying things like this:

```
var active_tab = $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" ).( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected" );
```

or

```
var active_tab = $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" ).find( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected" );
```

But obviously that doesn't work because the first part just resolves to a number.  Is there any way to do this that doesn't involve writing some id/class modifying on click events too keep track of whats open? Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The active tab has a class of `.ui-state-active`, so something like...

```
$('#accordion .ui-accordion-header').filter('.ui-state-active').index()
```

Except that index includes the tabs themselves too, so

```
$('#accordion .ui-accordion-header').filter('.ui-state-active').index() / 2
```

Comment: Did you change the selectors to whatever is correct for your implementation? I tested it on the jQuery UI Accordion demo page, so it definitely works :)

Comment: Well, I changed it to this: `alert($('.accordion .ui-accordion-header').filter('.ui-state-active').index());` but I don't quuuite understand the filter concept, I need to get the tab object that is inside the active accordian window, and with that code you never look at the .tab :S

Comment: It looks to see which header is active (because the corresponding tab should be active). If you paste some HTML, we can have a look at that too :)

Comment: Basically I have one accordion object with multiple rows, and inside each I have a "tabs" object.  I need to select the tabs object that is in the active accordion row.

Comment: Replace `.index()` with `.find('.tabs')`

Comment: Interesting, so along that train of thought, I'm trying something like this: `alert($(".accordion").filter(".ui-state-active").find(".tabs").tabs( "option", "selected" ));` but now I get an object back instead of a number... any ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7552/discussion-between-joe-and-supertron)